# Find out Monthly Percentage in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to find out monthly percentage (last 12 Months) for the below query

with severity wise, it would be great if anyone could help me out

```
SELECT Month(a.[Work Initated Date]) AS Month, a.[Initial Severity],

(CAST(Count(a.[Case Number]) AS Decimal(10,1))/ (select CAST(Count(a.[Case Number]) AS Decimal(10,1)) 

FROM [DSTRINING].[dbo].[SFDC WorkInitiated]  (nolock) a 


where  a.[Initial Severity]='Critical' AND Month(a.[Work Initated Date])=Month(getdate()))*100) AS 'Work Initated%'

FROM [DSTRINING].[dbo].[SFDC WorkInitiated]  (nolock) a

where a.[Initial Severity]='Critical' AND Month(a.[Work Initated Date])=Month(getdate()) AND a.[Work Initiated Target Breached]='NO' 

Group by Month(a.[Work Initated Date]), a.[Initial Severity]
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions for this.  Your query is a bit hard to follow, but . . .

```
select Year(wi.[Work Initated Date]) AS yyyy, Month(wi.[Work Initated Date]) AS mm,
       wi.[Initial Severity],
       count(*) * 100.0/ sum(count(*)) over partition by Year(wi.[Work Initated Date]), Month(wi.[Work Initated Date])) as [Work Initated%]
from [DSTRINING].[dbo].[SFDC WorkInitiated] wi
where  wi.[Initial Severity] = 'Critical' and
       Month(wi.[Work Initated Date]) = Month(getdate())) and
       wi.[Work Initiated Target Breached] = 'NO' 
Group by Year(wi.[Work Initated Date]), Month(wi.[Work Initated Date]), wi.[Initial Severity];
```

Notes:

- I included the year along with the month.  I just think that is a good practice to avoid unwanted errors.
- I changed the table alias to the initials of the table.  That makes the query easier to follow.
- The window function in the `select` calculates the ratio you want.
- I removed the conversion to `decimal(10, 1)`.  I think that confuses the query (although you can add it back in for your output purposes).

Comment: Gordon Linoff@Thanks for your reply, let me try

Comment: This is providing 100% for all the months which is incorrect here 'sum(count(*)) over partition by Year(wi.[Work Initated Date]), Month(wi.[Work Initated Date]))' should give total number of different months so that it will give correct percentage